# How to use linux repository for setup (ubuntu) when box are in aws scenario 2 wizard created private subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nat, amazon-vpc

I know lots of questions and I have personally tried manual VPC creation multiple times until I gave to the wizard (NAT concept wouldn't stick). I thought the wizard would actually configure everything out of the box so I can finally setup the boxes but it's not the case.

Let's correct some assumptions:

**1 :** On Aws documentation, NAT instance (t1.small) is meant to convey private subnet requests to the net does that imply that apt-get update should work?

**2 :** outbound messages means it can reach out resources on the net. Since apt-get is pulling down packages does that mean some how inbound rules are blocking that?

How can I make it work? below is my setup . NAT stuff was all from the wizard:

Security Group ON NAT

```
InBound  
All traffic All All sg-1xxxxx0 (default)
OutBound
All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0
```

Security Group on Ec2 box(database) in private subnet

```
MYSQL             TCP  3306   10.0.0.5/32 # app IP
MYSQL             TCP  3306   10.0.1.0/24 #private subnet
Custom TCP Rule   TCP  27017  10.0.0.5/32
Custom TCP Rule   TCP  27017  10.0.1.0/24
SSH               TCP  22     10.0.0.5/32
All ICMP          All  N/A    10.0.1.0/24
```

All I need is to let the boxes launched in the private subnet can to apt-get and let puppet agents contact puppetmaster.

How to achieve this? Thanks for your suggestion in advance

Below are the routing tables:

**EDIT:**

Routing tables

**1**

Routes

```
Destination   Target        Status  Propagated
10.0.0.0/16   local         Active  No
0.0.0.0/0     igw-9xxxxxe   Active  No
```

Subnet Associations

```
 subnet-9xxxx6 (10.0.0.0/24) | my-public-zone   10.0.0.0/24

 subnet-9xxxx5 (10.0.1.0/24) | my-private-zone 10.0.1.0/24
```

**2**

Routes

```
Destination       Target                     Status   Propagated
10.0.0.0/16       local                      Active   No
0.0.0.0/0         eni-fxxxxxxd / i-xxxxxxxx  Active   No
```

Subnet Associations

```
Subnet                                                CIDR
You do not have any subnet associations.
The following subnets have not been associated with any route tables and are therefore using the main table routes:

Subnet                                                CIDR
subnet-9xxxxxx5 (10.0.1.0/24) | my-private-zone       10.0.1.0/24
```

Comment: 1. Yes, if you did it correctly.

2. No, inbound rules would not affect that.

Comment: so some if wrong even though it's been created by the wizard. Can you assist with that? Do you need more details?

Comment: I'd check your routing tables.

Comment: Updated the post with details